# How to get the latest comment from a Jira story/Epic/Task

Tags: jira-rest-api

I have requirement to get the latest comment from a Jira issue. I am using rest api `jira/rest/api/2/issue/ASK-101/comment` to get all the comments for a particular issue. I am using jira atlassian version 2.

I update the comment using program so, i found same time stamp for few comments. Like below:

```
{                                              
    "id" : "920608",                            
    "body" : "Test987",                         
    "created" : "2016-04-14T12:25:06.000-0500", 
    "updated" : "2016-04-14T12:25:06.000-0500"  
} , {                                            
    "id" : "920609",                           
    "body" : "Test987",                        
    "created" : "2016-04-14T12:25:06.000-0500",
    "updated" : "2016-04-14T12:25:06.000-0500" 
}
```

So i can't find the latest comment with the latest timestamp as one timestamp can have multiple comment.
I see "ID" parameter which seems to be unique. Can i assume higher/max id will have the latest comment?
Is "ID" unique?
Does comment rest api guarantee to order comment data in sorted order, can i simply loop in comments array and assume last one is latest.

Comment: How did you create two comments at the same moment?

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
jira/rest/api/2/issue/ASK-101/comment?orderBy=-created&maxResults=1
```

It will give you exactly the last comment.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how you managed to add two comments at once. Maybe there's a bug in your Jira java client causing wrong dates to be reported? Check the REST API directly just to be sure.

Anyway. I haven't found any guarantees in the documentation about comment ids. From what I can see they seem to be sequential and unique (in JIRA 7 there's an experimental API `api/2/comment/{commentId}/properties` where comment id is used in a top-level resource so they seem to be global). Your options are:

1. return multiple latest comments (if it's allowable given your requirements)
2. choose the comment with the latest id in case the time stamps are the same
3. choose the comment randomly

I'd go with 2 if 1 is not an option. It's still better than 3, even if the assumption about ids is wrong.

## EDIT

As OP menioned in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36634761/how-to-get-the-latest-comment-from-a-jira-story-epic-task/36636095#comment60911325_36636095) a JIRA insider [confirmed that comment ids are sequential](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/Is-comment-id-sequential-in-jira-rest-api-issue-response/qaq-p/571303) (the later comment will get an id greater than an earlier one).

Comment: Thanks Jannis !! I checked with Jira folks and a/c to them greatest/highest comment id  will be the latest comment for an individual issue. https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/38389049/answers/38389629